# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, while trying to .map() an array passed through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am not sure why I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined here:

I am trying to pass an array down from App.js to => SearchResult.js to => TrackList.js

TrackList.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Track from '../Track/Track'
import '../TrackList/TrackList.css';

class TrackList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
        {this.props.tracks.map(track => {
          console.log(track);
          <Track track={track} />}
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TrackList;
```

the console.log(track) above returns an array of objects as expected, I think that makes sure that this.props.tracks is an array.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SearchBar from './Components/SearchBar/SearchBar';
import SearchResults from './Components/SearchResults/SearchResults';
import Playlist from './Components/Playlist/Playlist';

const track = {
  name: "Tiny Dancer",
  artist: 'Elton John',
  album: 'Madman Across The Water'
};

const tracks = [track, track, track];

class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {'searchResults': tracks};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Ja<span className="highlight">mmm</span>ing</h1>
        <div className="App">
          <SearchBar />
          <div className="App-playlist">
            <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults}/>
            <Playlist />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

SearchResults.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../SearchResults/SearchResults.css';
import TrackList from '../TrackList/TrackList';


class SearchResults extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="SearchResults">
        {/* {console.log(this.props.searchResults)} */}
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <TrackList tracks={this.props.searchResults}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchResults;
```

I also tried using props to pass the array from App.js (instead of state) but I got the same error.

Comment: Where is props even defined? Can't you see it's undefined ?

Comment: <SearchResults searchResults={this.state.searchResults}/> in the App.js please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can you add a console.log(this.props.tracks) at the beginning of the Tracklist's render function and share the results? Maybe the props.tracks are not always an array...

Comment: @Tobias it is logging the Tracks array

Comment: Are you sure it's the map function of the TrackList? Your code seems to be fine, can't find any errors

Comment: @Tobias I don't have map anywhere else. This is what the error is also telling me:       TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
TrackList.render
/src/Components/TrackList/TrackList.js:12
   9 | <div className="TrackList">
  10 | {console.log(this.props.tracks)}
  11 | 
> 12 |   {this.props.tracks.map(track => {
  13 |     console.log(track);
  14 |     <Track track={track} />}
  15 |   )}

Comment: Looks like your `props` should be reaching `<Tracklist/>` fine. Could the `<Playlist/>` component you render with no `props` be the source of the problem? Have you tried omitting it?

Comment: copied your code. works https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uxy9ns?file=Hello.js

Comment: you ARE missing `return` in your code. i assume you forgot it after adding the console log inside your map callback. wouldn't be the cause of your error though

Comment: is this your exact code or are you fetching the tracks from api?

Comment: Well a video chat or something like this would be more effective than guessing what's going on I think

Comment: @ArmanCharan THAAANKS that solved the problem. But this is a bit weird, do you know why this is generating an error?

Comment: Thanks to you all guys for your time. Much appreciated.

Comment: If you shared the code of the Playlist with us we could... but let me guess: You are iterating over tracks, too (by using map)

Comment: @Tobias yes you are right, I did not think that Playlist will be the issue as I have not introduced any functionality to it other than importing the TrackList and adding some JSX.

Comment: happens :-D have a nice day

Comment: Regardless of functionality; calling `properties` on `undefined` `variables` tends to break React apps. Best practice is to check whether or not `variables` exist before calling them and have an alternative case for when they don't exist. See [Error Handling in React 16](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sometimes react will render the app before your props loaded. this especially happens if you're getting props form an api call. react will throw an error if that happens. here's a work around:

```
import React from 'react';
import Track from '../Track/Track'
import '../TrackList/TrackList.css';

class TrackList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={}
    }
  render() {
      //es6 syntax. this will allow the app to render and then replace the 
      //tracks variable with this.props.tracks when the props are ready
      //this check if this.props.tracks exist and if it doesn't it will 
      //assign the variable to an empty array. then .map will not be 
      //called on an undefined variable.  
      let tracks = this.props.tracks ? this.props.tracks : [];
    return (
      <div className="TrackList">
        {tracks.map(track => {
          console.log(track);
          <Track track={track} />}
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TrackList;
```

Comment: Even better would be to use [`defaultProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values)